# how to get the absolute path for files based on fid

Tags: files, uri

How can i get the absolute path for a file based on the fid? Sorry if this is a repeat, I did a search but was unable to find the answer.

Comment: I might have figured out a way to get it using the $base_url + the remaining path to files + uri   is this the best way?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Drupal 7**

This is a two part process, using [`file_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_load/7) and [`file_create_url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7)

First, you need to turn the $fid into a Drupal URI:

```
$file = file_load($fid);
$uri = $file->uri;
```

Now, you can turn this into a URL

```
$url = file_create_url($uri);
```

`file_create_url()` always creates an absolute URL, either using the global `$base_path` that you have defined, or using the one that Drupal guessed during bootstrap.

Comment: I am surprised you have to load the file just to get the path, seems like a waste of resources.

Comment: @Russ It's loading the file object, not the file itself.  You could also do a db_query to get the uri, but I try to use the API as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that, just thought there would be a clean function that could return it in one step. Maybe something to consider in drupal 8.

Comment: always I see $fid in answers or tuto but from where?

Comment: In your example you have 'field_load($fid)', it should be 'file_load($fid)'.

Comment: @SteveMulvihill Wow, nice catch. Four+ years and 33 votes, and nobody noticed that.

Answer (score 10):

#### Drupal 8

```
$file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($file_id);
$uri = $file->getFileUri();
$url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri(file_create_url($uri))->toString();
```

Comment: It works also only by calling file_create_url($uri); which is already returning the URL as a string.

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal 7 you can also use MYSQL query, if you don't want to load all the fields of the file

```
  $fid = 1; //your file ID
  $uri = db_select('file_managed', 'f')
    ->condition('f.fid', $fid, '=')
    ->fields('f', array('uri'))
    ->execute()->fetchField();
  echo file_create_url($uri);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Drupal 9**

All previous answers are now deprecated using Drupal 9.
There is a perfect list of the up-to-date alternatives : https://www.drupal.org/node/2940031

An example step by step :

```
$file = File::load(15);  
$uri = $file->getFileUri();
$url = \Drupal::service('file_url_generator')->generate($uri);
// Your url as a string
$string = $url ->toString();
```

Comment: \Drupal::service('file_url_generator')->generateAbsoluteString($uri);

Answer (score 0):

These are both working for me in Drupal 8:

```
// top of file
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

// load the file object from some file id
$file_object = File::load(123);

// way 1
$file_uri = $file_object->uri->value;
$file_url = file_create_url($file_uri);

// way 2
$file_uri = $file_object->getFileUri();
$file_url = Url::fromUri(file_create_url($file_uri))->toString();
```