# Generate image URL from FID

Tags: 8, media

I have a custom form in Drupal 8, which has a image upload field. I am storing the file ID of that uploaded image. Now I need to generate the URL of that image.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/105064/how-to-get-the-absolute-path-for-files-based-on-fid

Comment: are you looking to display on twig template file or in class?

Comment: @vgoradiya I am using twig template.
Actually I am creating rows and passing that data in table.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Get the image file src (url)

```
$fid = 1;//The file ID   
$file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid);
$path = $file->getFileUri();
```

OR

```
$path = 'public://images/image.jpg';
$url = \Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle::load('medium')->buildUrl($file->getFileUri());
```

Comment: In your second snippet there's an unused variable `$path`. What is this? Or is it the dump of the `$path` variable from the first snippet?

Answer (score 1):

This way you can get your stored image file using fid in your custom module

```
$myconfig = \Drupal::config('yourmodule.settings');
$fid = $myconfig->get('image');

foreach ($fid as $key => $value) {
  $fid1 = $value;
}

$file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid1);
$path = $file->getFileUri();
```