# Get url from File ID

Tags: theming, 8, files

I used a form controller to store an image in configuration settings. Like so.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

$config = $this->config('custom.settings');

$form['icon'] = [
   '#type' => 'managed_file',
   '#default_value' => $config->('icon'),
   '#upload_location' => 'public://',
];

}

public function submitForm(array&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
        if (!empty($form_state->getValue('icon'))) {
            $image_fid = $form_state->getValue('icon');

            $file_name = File::load($image_fid[0])->getFilename();
            $file_url  = '/sites/default/files'.$file_name;

            $file_uri = File::load($image_fid[0])->getFileUri();
            file_save_data(file_get_contents($file_uri), $file_uri, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
            $this->config('foundation.settings')
                 ->set('icon', $form_state->getValue('icon'))
                ->save();

            $file       = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($image_fid[0]);
            $file_usage = \Drupal::service('file.usage');
            $file_usage->add($file, 'Standard', 'file', $image_fid[0]);
        }
}
```

I then attempt to grab the file in my .theme file to be used in twig templates like so

```
function AAEP_foundation_preprocess_page(&$variables){  
    $variables['icons'] = [
        'icon1_file' => \Drupal::config('foundation.settings')->get('icon'),
    ];
}
```

I then use {{ icons.icon1_file[0] }} in my template but it only produces the file ID rather than the actual url to the image. Also after searching through sites/default/files I can't seem to find the images that were meant to uploaded so I'm concerned that the files were not actually saved. How would I get the URL based on the image id? Also is there any issue with how I saved the file in submitForm()?

Comment: Does this not answer your question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/105064/how-to-get-the-absolute-path-for-files-based-on-fid ??

Comment: I believe that answer is for drupal 7

Comment: Sorry bout that ... how bout this: 

            $file_url = File::load($image_fid[0])->url();

Comment: I can't see where your $file_url variable is used.